# How to get a relative path from a given absolute path

Tags: relative-path, absolute-path

How do I get out of the absolute path:

```
"C:/Users/test1234/workspace/Read/Test.txt"
```

the relative path?
I thought the corresponding relative path looks like this:

```
".../Read/Test.txt"
```

but the file is not found, although the .txt file lies in the same directory as the java program. The file could be read with the absolute path, but I need the relative one.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as *the* relative path from an absolute path. It all depends on your current location.

But in your case I think you should replace the three dots by two dots. So make it:

```
"../Read/Test.txt"
```

(At least if your current location is C:/Users/test1234/workspace/Whatever/)